# Create user in keycloak through keycloak admin client returns 400

Tags: java, keycloak

I want to create a user through keycloak admin client but I am getting a 400 status.

- I cannot activate any logs of the keycloak client so I have no idea about the http call it performs.
- I have managed to create a user through postman.
- Search and get user work (see below)

Do you see any errors in my code?

```
       Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(keycloakUrl,"master",
     keycloakAdminUsername, keycloakAdminPassword,
                     keycloakAdminClient);
            UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
            user.setUsername("username");
            user.setFirstName("firstname");
            user.setEmail("kjhkjh@gmail.com");
            user.setRequiredActions(Collections.<String>emptyList());
            user.setEnabled(true);

            Response response = keycloak.realm(realm).users().create(user);
            if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
                log.error("Couldn't create user, status:{}", response.getStatus());
                } else {
                    log.info("User# created", user.getUsername());
                    log.info("Keycloak response status: {}", 
response.getStatus());
                    }
```

> Couldn't create user, status:400

The thing is, if I try to get a user using the same keycloak instance, it works.

```
UserResource userX = keycloak.realm(realm).users().get("8c1d29fd-8d6b-4dea-817f-3fc1421096f0");
log.debug(userX.toRepresentation().getUsername());
```

Same, if I use the search

```
log.debug("Getting users from keycloak");
    List<UserRepresentation> users = keycloak.realm(realm).users().search(username, 0, 10);
    users.forEach(user -> log.info("username: {}", user.getUsername()));
```

Comment: Is that `kc` variable ever used or a typo (i.e. should it be `keycloak` instead)?

Comment: indeed, it was a bad copy paste, I have corrected it

Comment: I did the same a while ago but unfortunately I can't access the code atm and my memory doesn't serve me too well so I can only give some hints on what you could try: 1) check your admin user is allowed to create and manage users in your realm 2) try without the required actions (iirc they don't work here anyways) 3) try to send a (temporary) password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found the solution, kind of stupid to my eyes. The client needs to be the same version with the keycloak server. In my case for example I got the 2.0.0.Final version of the keycloak admin client because the keycloak server is 2.0.0. It is all about the UserRepresentation class as far as I understood.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. What do you mean by "client version same with keycloak server" ? I'm using Keycloak 7.0.0 standalone server, where do I check for client version?

Comment: @Utkarsh Gupta you've probably solved the problem by now but, he meant that the version of the keycloak maven dependencies need to be the same as that of Keycloak itself. For example, I'm using Keycloak 6.0.1 so I need to use version 6.0.1 of the dependencies, too.

Comment: @nonzaprej There seems to be an issue with the latest Keycloak release itself too; read about it in the Github discussion. I'm running Keycloak 7.0.0 as the server. I was facing issues when I was running the latest keycloak client, i.e. 7.0.1. Downgraded the version to 6.0.x and the issues were gone. They're well aware of the issues in the release and recommended using the earlier version of the client instead.